# flex 3 how to programatically bind properties of 2 objects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

so in mxml it's

```
<mx:z id="a" 
...
<mx:z id="b" value="{a.value}"
```

how do you do this in actionscript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BindingUtils.bindProperty()`.

See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindProperty%28%29).